# Why few of my symbols don't appear in my .so file?

Tags: android, c++, linker, java-native-interface, linker-flags

I am creating an Android native application, where I have many cpp files and few kt files. With the use of cpp files, I am compiling static libraries which gives me .a extension files and as a whole I am combining these into an .so file.

As, its a native application System.loadLibrary("LibName") will be called during startup which calls JNI_onLoad (JavaVM *  pJavaVM, void * pReserved).

Now problem occurs here, In one of the Cpp files, I am only having two functions JNI_onLoad and JNI_OnUnload. Now, when it is in this way while dumping .so file I don't see the symbols of these two functions but while dumping .a file the symbols are present.

But if I create a static variable and use it in JNI_onLoad then in my .so file I am able to see the symbols.

I have also gone through one [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) of linker flags where "-E" flag refers to the linker to add all the symbols into the table. Tried adding this too but didn't work.

Am I missing something here? Not able to figure this out why this happens. Thanks in advance.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JNI_OnLoad (JavaVM * pJavaVM, [[maybe_unused]] void * pReserved)
{
         JNIEnv *    env;
         int      ret_val;

    if (!pJavaVM)
        return JNI_ERR;

    if (pJavaVM->GetEnv ((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
       return JNI_ERR;
   
   //  We are doing our own operations 

    return env->GetVersion ();
}
```

Build steps:

We compile our cpp files with Clang compiler and using CMake we generate our .a library files and using linker we create our resultant .so file.

```
# Sets the minimum CMake version required for this project.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

# Declares the project name. The project name can be accessed via ${ PROJECT_NAME},
# Since this is the top level CMakeLists.txt, the project name is also accessible
# with ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} (both CMake variables are in-sync within the top level
# build script scope).
project("MyProject")

#Please add path of cpp files in below add_library command
add_library(Lib1 STATIC JNI.cpp) 

add_library(Lib2 STATIC AnotherFile.cpp)

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED native-lib.cpp) 

target_link_libraries (${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Lib1 Lib2 log android)
```

Comment: Edit your question with a [mre] of the cpp file containing your JNI_OnLoad function as well as the build steps you used.

Comment: I have updated the question @Botje with what you have asked.

Comment: Details matter. Show your cmakelists.txt. And the final linker step as well if you do that outside of cmake for some weird reason...

Comment: Sorry for late response @Botje, Added the CMakeLists.txt and the linker step is also here too

Comment: The linker has discarded the symbols in your static libraries because they aren't used. See the linked duplicate for a solution, I was able to get it to work by changing Lib1 and Lib2 to OBJECT, but  the TARGET_OBJECTS generator was not necessary.

Comment: Thanks I was able to do it via changing into object but is it possible via remaining on static libraries? 

@Botje I have tried the 'static lib' solution which you have linked and also tried the below code. But facing few difficulties. Am I missing something here? 










target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        # List libraries link to the target library
        $$<LINK_LIBRARY:WHOLE_ARCHIVE, Lib1>
        $$<LINK_LIBRARY:WHOLE_ARCHIVE, Lib2>
        log
        android)

Comment: Those double dollar signs are not needed. Other than that I think that should work according to the documentation...